# Usages of [liferay-aui] and [alloy-ui]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Within stackoverflow, [liferay-aui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liferay-aui) and [alloy-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alloy-ui) seem to be used interchangeably. With so few questions involved regarding either tag some may view this as insignificant, however, I did want to spark a discussion regarding the ambiguity involved with their usages.

The AlloyUI tag has a suggestion (`questions which involve using alloy-ui taglibs in liferay`). Personally, I could see that context belonging to [liferay-aui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liferay-aui), but as soon as you involve events or anything beyond basic rendering you also require/enter [alloy-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alloy-ui) domain.

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965703/auivalidator-tag-not-working-in-jsp-page) doesn't require anything beyond the basic taglib and appears appropriately tagged, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542226/unable-to-create-popup-in-liferay) should be tagged [alloy-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alloy-ui) (many more examples can be found like this).

With AlloyUI distinguishing itself from Liferay, I could see the potential need for [liferay-aui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liferay-aui) to stick around, but can't quite come up with when it would be appropriately used by itself, except for the example I provided.

At this point, I see a `Choose your own discussion`:

- establish a wiki for [liferay-aui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liferay-aui) and make an attempt at a decisive division between the two
- or [liferay-aui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liferay-aui) rolls into [alloy-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alloy-ui)
- `<insert>` your suggestion here!

Answer (score 5):

I vote that we:

> establish a wiki for [liferay-aui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liferay-aui) and make an attempt at a decisive division between the two

Here's why:

- [alloy-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alloy-ui) can be used outside of Liferay.
- Some [liferay-aui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liferay-aui) tags may actually have very little to do with [alloy-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alloy-ui). For example there is `<aui:button-row>` which is not related to [alloy-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alloy-ui) at all and simply uses CSS which exists only in Liferay Portal.
- The experts for each topic don't actually have much overlap. For example, I know quite a lot about [alloy-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alloy-ui), but very little about `aui` JSP taglibs.
- If someone is using an `aui` JSP tag which does utilize [alloy-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alloy-ui) they can simply use both tags and it makes their question more descriptive.